# What is the best way to use DateFormatters in UITableViews cellForRowAt method

Tags: ios, swift, dateformatter

I have a table view which has few cells. I need to display the date in a human-readable format whose raw format is retrieved from the API call. I am using the below code to call the convertToDate function which takes care of taking raw date string of format "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX" and converting it to "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a". However as we know Date formatters can be expensive. Can anyone please help me answer a few questions looking at the below code implementation?

Note : I am calling the function convertToDate from my cellForRowAt method inside tableView

1. Is it good practice to create a singleton class so that only one Dateformatter instance is created ( so it is less expensive )
2. I am also creating a DispatchQueue which is concurrent so that Dateformatter is thread-safe. Is that good practice?
3. Will calling convertToDate with convertToDate which is concurrent cause any lag in performance when scroll table views?
4. Are there any standard references to handle/create Dateformatter in general?

Below code converts: "2023-12-22T13:17:27Z" to "December 22, 2023 at 01:17 PM"

Code

```
import Foundation

class DateUtils {
    
    static let shared = DateUtils()
    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
    
    // Date formatter are not thread safe and adding this to a concurrent queue makes if safer.
    // For table views cells this may have minimal impact and needs to have performance tested in different cases where used.
    private let dateFormatterQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "com.example.dateformatter",
                                                   attributes: .concurrent)
    
    private init(){}
    
    func convertToDate(from date: String,
                       with format: String = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssX",
                       to: String = "MMMM dd, yyyy 'at' hh:mm a") -> String? {
        
        var formattedDate: String?
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = format
        guard let date = dateFormatter.date(from: date) else {
            return nil
        }
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = to
        
        dateFormatterQueue.sync {
            formattedDate = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
        }
        return formattedDate
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. No, a static property in an extension of `DateFormatter` would be the better choice.
2. No.
3. No.
4. No `Dateformatter` needed

The API call returns most likely JSON.

In the model define the property representing the date

```
let date: Date
```

and add the `.iso8601` strategy to the decoder to convert the ISO string to `Date` on the fly

```
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .iso8601
```

In the cell format the date the modern way

```
cell.date = item.date.formatted( Date.FormatStyle()
                     .year()
                     .month(.wide)
                     .day(.twoDigits)
                     .hour(.twoDigits(amPM: .abbreviated))
                     .minute()
                     .locale(.init(identifier: "en_US")))
```

The style can also be defined externally.

Comment: Great, I am able to get output as  "January 16, 2023 at 10:49 AM" without any formatters which is great as I do not have to worry about all the singletons, thread-safe anymore etc

Any reason you have chosen the hardcoded locale to be en_US instead of Locale.current ?

Comment: Because you get a different (localized) output for example in Japan, France or Germany.

Comment: Using just the FormatStyle does make life simpler. When do you think we should be using DateFormatters then ?

Comment: Actually `formatted()` is able to replace all kinds of date formatters.